# С WinForms на WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

Есть вот такой код на Win Form

1)

```
if (sfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
```

Пробовал вот так

```
 if (saveFileDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
```

вроде работает? но не знаю правильно или нет?

2)

```
private void frmAbout_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lblProductName.Text = $"Product Name: {Application.ProductName}"; 
            lblProductVersion.Text = $"Product Version: {Application.ProductVersion}";
            lblCopyright.Text = "Copyright © 2018";
        }
```

не могу переделать его в WPF

Comment: Хотите делать правильно - изучайте MVVM. Диалоги по правилам MVVM создаются отдельно (со своей VM и своими событиями), а что касается второго кода, так это полностью противоречит MVVM, ибо ваш код не должен знать о элементах, да и о View подавно.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ По поводу изучения вы правы и со временем думаю понимание придёт. Ну а, пока я столкнулся с такой проблемой и мне нужно её решить сейчас. А, про проводу второго кода, он написан на WinForms и там он работает мне нужно просто перевести его в WPF ,а там не работают только (`Text`) и (`ProductName`) в интернете я не нашёл как решить эту проблему. Но я уверен что это можно сделать.

Comment: Ну если надо "решить сейчас", то зачем тогда спрашиваете "правильно ли?". А во втором коде - вы даже не указали что конкретно не работает. В чем проблема? Не знаете как задать имя элементу, присвоить текст или что?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ  Правильно или нет я спросил за тем, что может есть ещё способ решить данный пример. Так как это единственный способ который у меня заработал.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ  Второй код должен в окно About выводить данные из  (Сведение о сборке) Название, Версия и Copyright в данном случае. Там 3 Label в первый (lblProductName) идёт название программы и так далее. В Wpf не работают ( (Text) выдаёт `Label не содержит определение для Text  и не удалось найти метод Text` и (ProductName) `Application не содержит определение для "ProductName"` ) Хотя в WinForms все работает! Но так как я только начал практиковать написание программ я не могу пока разобраться. С первым примером разобрался ,а вот со вторым не могу.

Comment: Текст задается обычно в `.Text` либо `.Content`. По поводу версии -  Хранится это все вроде как в `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName()`. На будущее, пожалуйста, задавайте вопрос развернуто, добавляйте все ваши попытки, что пробовали и что от нас ожидаете. Ибо я сейчас сижу и гадаю, как думаете, нравится?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Да, вы правы. Извиняюсь. Вот .Text как  раз и не работает. Выдаёт вот такую ошибку ( Label не содержит определение для Text и не удалось найти метод Text) ,Content не пробовал попробую!Спасибо!